# Nodejs authorization with box api

Tags: node.js, api, http, box-api

I am trying to connect to get token from Box api in nodejs. I am through with first level authorization and got auth code, my callback url is being called. But, I am getting error when I tried to get token. Below is my callback code,

```
app.get('/auth/box', function(req, res){
var client_id = oauthSecrets.box.clientId;
console.log('clientid:'+client_id)
var provider = 'box';
var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/box/callback';
var boxAuthUrl =     'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id='
        + client_id + '&state=authenticated&redirect_uri='+ redirect_uri;
console.log('boxAuthUrl:'+boxAuthUrl);
res.redirect(boxAuthUrl); 
});

var authCode = '';  
var clientId = oauthSecrets.box.clientId;
var clientSecret = oauthSecrets.box.clientSecret;

app.get('/auth/:provider/callback', function(req, res){

console.log('box callback return');
authCode = res.req.query.code;
console.log('authCode:'+authCode);
var oauthPath = '/api/oauth2/token'; 
var data = ' -d ' +
  '\'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + authCode +
  '&client_id=' + clientId +
  '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '\'';
oauthPath = oauthPath + data;
console.log('oauth path:' + oauthPath);

// the post options
var optionspost = {
  host : 'https://www.box.com/',
  path : oauthPath,
  method : 'POST'
};

var reqPost = http.request(optionspost, function(res2) {
console.log("statusCode: ", res2.statusCode); 
res2.on('data', function(d) {
  console.info('POST result:\n');
  process.stdout.write(d);
  console.info('\n\nPOST completed');
});

});

reqPost.end();
reqPost.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error('=====Error:'+e);
  console.error('=====Error:'+e.stack);
});

});
```

I am getting socket reset error here `reqPost.on('error', function(e)`.
Anything wrong in the code, or suggestions please.

EDIT: Below error message

```
=====Error:Error: read ECONNRESET 
=====Error:Error: read ECONNRESET     
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)     
at TCP.onread (net.js:556:19)
```